# Add class to the elements stored in a variable JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table, of which all the `<td>` is stored in a variable called `var = td`. Now upon clicking the `<td>` of `<table>` I am generating a random number `var = randomNumber` with jquery (0-9) and I want to select the **td** from the array on the basis of random number generated. (ie) if the random number is 2, then 2nd `<td>` from  `var = td` and add a class **red** to the td.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/pycy77w8/

I Hope I am clear on what I want. Else please let me know. Thanks for help

Comment: `$(randomTd).addClass('red');` ? [**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/x1j5fhu3/) . Note, you have to use "-1"  `td[randNum-1]` as the array index always starts with `0`

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`$( td.get(Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random()*td.length))) ).addClass("red");`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.